# Node Red TI sensortag

Tags: node.js, raspbian, node-red

I use the Node Red node from the following link:
https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/tree/master/hardware/sensorTag

It works great, but I can't find an option to change the read interval time. Is there a possibility to change this time (for example to 500ms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The node does not expose any options to change the interval it sends readings from the SensorTag.

Comment: Thank you, what is necessary to add this functionality?

Comment: Hi, the node would need updating to expose the options - assuming the underlying API supports different reporting intervals. SO isn't the place to discuss feature enhancements. Please follow-up on the node-red mailing list (linked from nodered.org)